# Create a custom font style for beamer

Tags: beamer, fonts, color

How can I create a custom font style for beamer? How can I then change the color of this style and the normal font color globally?

I'd like to write e.g.:

```
\begin{frame}
    \HighlightedText{I am special}\\
    Here is a normal paragraph.
\end{frame}
```

I think that it has to be adjusted with `setbeamercolor` but I don't know how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding the normal text font, you can change it by installing the `normal text` color using something like

```
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=blue}
```

see example code below.

Regarding the highlighted text, first recall that `beamer` already provides the `\alert` command which gives the functionality that you seem to be looking for. In any case, if you want to provide your own settings, below I show two options. You can do something basic such as defining a color and a font:

```
% color for the new highlighted text
\setbeamercolor{hltext}{fg=olive}
% font for the new highlighted text
\setbeamerfont{Hl text}{size=\huge}
```

and then defining a command applying that color and font specification:

```
\newcommand<>\HighlightedText[1]{\only#2{{\usebeamercolor[fg]{hltext}\usebeamerfont{Hl text}#1}}}
```

Another option is to define something more elaborate similar to the `\alert` command. Again, the first step is to set color and font as before, and then

```
% An improved version
\defbeamertemplate*{Hl text begin}{default}{\setbeamercolor{local structure}{parent=alerted text}}
\newenvironment{hlenv}
  {%
    \begin{altenv}%
    {\usebeamertemplate{Hl text begin}\usebeamercolor[fg]{hltext}%
      \usebeamerfont{Hl text}%
    }{\usebeamertemplate{Hl text end}}{\color{.}}{}%
  }
  {\end{altenv}}
\newcommand<>{\Hltext}[1]{\begin{hlenv}#2\relax#1\end{hlenv}}
```

Here's a complete exmaple:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% color for the normal text
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=blue}
% color for the alerted text
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=magenta}
% color for the new highlighted text
\setbeamercolor{hltext}{fg=olive}
% font for the new highlighted text
\setbeamerfont{Hl text}{size=\huge}

% A rudimentary version
\newcommand<>\HighlightedText[1]{\only#2{{\usebeamercolor[fg]{hltext}\usebeamerfont{Hl text}#1}}}

% An improved version
\defbeamertemplate*{Hl text begin}{default}{\setbeamercolor{local structure}{parent=alerted text}}
\newenvironment{hlenv}
  {%
    \begin{altenv}%
    {\usebeamertemplate{Hl text begin}\usebeamercolor[fg]{hltext}%
      \usebeamerfont{Hl text}%
    }{\usebeamertemplate{Hl text end}}{\color{.}}{}%
  }
  {\end{altenv}}
\newcommand<>{\Hltext}[1]{\begin{hlenv}#2\relax#1\end{hlenv}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\HighlightedText<1->{I am special.}\par
Here is a normal paragraph.\par
\Hltext<2->{I am special.}\par
\alert<3->{I am special.}\par
\begin{hlenv}<4>
I am special.
\end{hlenv}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And an animation of the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! How could I make the `\HighlightedText` bold? I tried to insert `\textbf{}` like this: `\newcommand<>\HighlightedText[1]{\only#2{{\usebeamercolor[fg]{\textbf{hltext}}\usebeamerfont{Hl text}#1}}}` but it doesn't work.

Comment: @sqe Use `\setbeamerfont{Hl text}{series=\bfseries}` and the definition for the command is the same:
`\newcommand<>\HighlightedText[1]{\only#2{{\usebeamercolor[fg]{hltext}\usebeamerfont{Hl text}#1}}}`

Comment: Thanks. It takes some time but I might understand beamer eventually. ;-)